# Hide twitter bootstrap button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make a twitter bootstrap modal button not appear on certain conditions, so that it dont show up when opening the modal?

And on another condition turn it back on again.

```
<a href="#" id="edit-modal-button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"> Edit </a>
```

**Update**:

The button to hide is inside the modal

Ive tried the following to no avail

```
$("edit-modal-button").css('display','none'); 

$('edit-modal-button').hide();
```

Comment: Not with data-attribute, but using javascript/jQuery yes...

Comment: You can check for the modal visibility with $(".modal").is(":visible"); and toggle hide() on the button.

Comment: The modal is not visible when the call is made. I whan to set the button not to show up Before the modal is visible. Ive tried the following to no avail  //$("edit-modal-button").css('display','none');
                     $('edit-modal-button').hide();

Comment: Try: $('#edit-modal-button').hide();

Comment: So the button you want to hide is inside the modal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the button's ID is edit-modal-button; `$('#edit-modal-button').hide();` will work, you just have to put in `#` to indicate you are referring to the elements ID.