# How to put a condition at Datatables button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to put a condition to check if data not null then "Not Found" button will appear, otherwise it will be hidden. Assuming client side received Ajax response from API.

[image]

```js
success: function(response){
    var result;
    
    if (response.data != null){
        result = "dataNotNull";
    } else {
        result = "dataNull";
    }

    loadFunc(result);
}

function loadFunc(result){
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Missmatch',
                titleAttr: 'Download in Excel',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    func_expMissMatch();
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Not Found',
                titleAttr: 'Download in Excel',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    func_expNotFound();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function loadFunc(result){
    let buttons = [];
    if (result === "dataNotNull") {
        buttons.push({
            text: 'Missmatch',
            titleAttr: 'Download in Excel',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                func_expMissMatch();
            },
        });
    }
    else{
        buttons.push({
            text: 'Not Found',
            titleAttr: 'Download in Excel',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                func_expNotFound();
            },
        });
    }
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        buttons: buttons,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Boostrap, you can hide the button with

```
$('#my-button').hide();
```

Where `#my-button` needs to be the `id` of the button element.
So...

```
if (response.data != null){
    $('#my-button').show();
} else {
    $('#my-button').hide();
}
```

[Hide twitter bootstrap button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424405/hide-twitter-bootstrap-button)